# How to allow BIOS to select boot drive instead of GRUB2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

New to Linux.
I have a primary drive with Windows 7 installed and a secondary with Ubuntu 20.04(I think).
Problem: when rebooting to change OS, GRUB2 fails and goes to grub recovery until I've rebooted to BIOS several times and mucked about in the BIOS boot priorities.
After getting into linux again, updating software makes Linux the first boot option.

I want it to boot windows if left uninterupted and linux on command from BIOS without all the fuss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Grub is boot-strapped by the MBR of the BIOS selected drive, the MBR pointing to the location of /boot/grub/ or the real grub code.  If you have multiple drives, it is the machine BIOS or UEFI code that controls which of those drives is used. Your heading is already how `grub` works as it's the only way it can work (hardware has always done that as it's the standard set by IBM in the 1980s, esp. before uEFI)

Comment: Your issue appears to be changing settings in BIOS can alter the drives, and how they appear to all OSes, so on some hardware you can have trouble when the order is changed (this is not a software issue, but the consequence of BIOS changing the way drives appear, and is machine specific). You have provided insufficient & only vague details on your setup so I at least cannot help with this issue.  I don't think it's you being 'new' to 'linux', more you not understanding how your machine boots an OS (general pc knowledge at issue), but I could be mistaken. Is your box BIOS or UEFI?

Comment: UEFI The reason I assumed it was a problem is because I never encountered this issue until I installed linux on a HD. When booting from a live USB grub never fails and goes to recovery. What other details can I provide that may help in correcting this?

Comment: What OS/release are you using? (*you mention only that you think it's Ubuntu 20.04 without details as to desktop, server or if it's in fact Ubuntu 20.04*). When installed did you change BIOS/UEFI settings? and then change those settings post-install? Is your machine is *Secure Boot* mode (being win7 your box maybe too old for that anyway), and was win7 and *unknown possibly 20.04* OS installed in the same mode? (*if they were installed in different modes - that's your problem as they won't work together nicely; you need to install both in the same way*).

Comment: Win 7 Pro 64bit on SSD. Ubuntu 20.04.1 desktop AMD 64 on HD. Secure Boot is enabled. There is an option for OS type being either Windows UEFI or Other OS; currently on Windows UEFI. The Compatability Support module is enabled. Boot Device Control is set to UEFI and Legacy OPROM. I'm not sure what you mean by mode. When I built this PC I installed Win 7 on the SSD and went to town. When I installed ubuntu I don't remember a mode option other than Install over other OS or install alongside other OS.